# Preventing itemize environment to insert initial vertical space

Tags: tables, lists, itemize, tabularx

I'm using itemize and tables like the following

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\ttfamily}llX}
 \toprule
 \textbf{\rmfamily Operator} & \textbf{Typen} & \textbf{Regel} \\
 \midrule
 = & Alle Typen &
  \begin{itemize}
   \item This is how we roll
   \item Maybe we can talk?
  \end{itemize} \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

But it keeps inserting a vertical space before the itemized list. How can I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Lists like `itemize` act differently if they are used within a `minipage` environment. Specifically, they don't insert that vertical space before. So, you could use a `minipage` environment inside the table cell for the `itemize` list. There's a trick which is more handy - define this command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
```

Now just use `\compress` before `\begin{itemize}`. You could even use it within the column definition, if you also load the `array` package:

```
\usepackage{array}
...
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\ttfamily}ll>{\compress}X}
```

Output of your example using this command:

[image]

The vertical space before `itemize` is gone. If you would like to compress the lists even more, have a look at

- the [`paralist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist) package, which offers a `compactitem` environment for that purpose, or
- the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package which allows easy customization of list environments, for example `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt]`, it even provides global configuration commands for lists.

But even with `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]` I would additionally use `\compress`.

Comment: Ohh i see. Any idea why it adds that space by default? Is that so one doesn't have to issue a ` \\ ` in the normal usecase before the lists? Where can one find information such as `\@minipagetrue`? Is that listed in some manual somewhere? What other stuff is affected by that special "magic" command? I'm trying to avoid a minipage, because I generally don't know the width of the `X` column of the table, but I would need to know it for the `minipage`.

Comment: `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]` was the first thing I tried. It had a smaller amount of space, but it was still there. I didn't look into why. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @TH.: Lists use `\addvspace`. This command doesn't add vertical space if `@minipage` is true. This way the `minipage` environment avoids extra vertical space at the top. We do the same here for lists - so `\topsep` and perhaps other values used at the beginning of the list don't matter any more.

Comment: @Johannes: In source2e.pdf, 16.5 Vertical spacing, you can find the information regarding `\addvspace` and `@minipage`. List items then set `\@minipage` to false using `\everypar`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm not sure I understand the rationale behind that design. As this question shows, there are situations other than minipages one might wish to not have such space.

Comment: Can you use this with a `p` column?

Comment: What exactly is `\@minipagetrue`?

Answer (score 2):

Also consider something like this:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
....
\begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=5mm]
    \item Satisfy individual's needs for affiliation
    \item Develop individual's sense of identity
    \item Reduce individual's axiety and feelings of insecurity and powerlessness
\end{itemize}
```

The `nosep` kills all vertical spacing, `leftmargin` halves the horizontal space between the table left border and the bullets

Comment: `nosep` kills vertical spacing inside, but not above.