# Suppress top skip between own frame environment and itemize

Tags: spacing, lists, framed, mdframed

I need to typset a book with a given definition of `{itemize}` and I added a `{framed}` environment by using `mdframed`. If the first line inside `{framed}` is normal text everything is fine

[image: normal text]

but if it starts with an `{itemize}` environment there is some extra space I can’t delete.

[image: itemize]

The skip before the end of the frame is okay in both cases. If I comment out the redefinition of `{itemize}` the skips are also okay.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{itemize}{%
    \begin{list}{\labelitemi}{%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\parindent}{1em}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\parindent}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
        \def\makelabel##1{\rlap{\normalfont\nobreak ##1}\hss}
    }%
}{%
    \end{list}
}


\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xparse}% doesn't work without this package ... ???
\newenvironment{framed}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        middlelinewidth=0.5pt,
        splittopskip=8pt,
        splitbottomskip=2pt,
        innertopmargin=9.39749pt,
        innerbottommargin=9.39749pt,
        innerleftmargin=9.39749pt,
        innerrightmargin=9.39749pt,
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{framed}
    \blindtext
\end{framed}
\blindtext
\begin{framed}
    \blinditemize
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

I tried to compare the new definition with the one from `source2e` but I didn’t find the difference causing the extra space. I found the [`\@minipagetrue` trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6454/4918) but that doesn’t help.

**Question**
How can I tell `{itemize}` to not insert space if it starts a frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two comment signs were missing, and this created spurious spaces.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{itemize}{%
    \begin{list}{\labelitemi}{%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\parindent}{1em}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\parindent}% <-- THIS ONE WAS MISSING
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}% <-- AND THIS ONE, TOO
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
        \def\makelabel##1{\rlap{\normalfont\nobreak ##1}\hss}% <-- Shouldn't harm
    }%
}{%
    \end{list}
}


\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xparse}% doesn't work without this package ... ???
\newenvironment{framed}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        middlelinewidth=0.5pt,
        splittopskip=8pt,
        splitbottomskip=2pt,
        innertopmargin=9.39749pt,
        innerbottommargin=9.39749pt,
        innerleftmargin=9.39749pt,
        innerrightmargin=9.39749pt,
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{framed}
    \blindtext
\end{framed}
\blindtext
\begin{framed}
    \blinditemize
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```