# How to eliminate vertical space before and after verse environment?

Tags: tables, spacing, verse

I'm using the `verse` package to typeset poems inside a `tabular` environment.  Is it possible to eliminate the space before and after the verse package?

```
\usepackage{verse}
...
\begin{tabular}{p{30mm} | p{30mm} | p{30mm}}
  \hline
    1.
  &
\begin{verse}
AAAA \\
BBBB \\
CCCC
\end{verse}
  & QUESTION \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: output of MWE]

I could manually insert vertical space before and after the `verse` environment,

```
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\vspace{-2.6pt}
```

but this seems to be an ugly solution.  There should be a more elegant solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `verse` environment is based upon the basic `list` environment, the `\compress` part of [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6454/16595) is valid here, too.

But there's still space added after the `verse` environment, that's why I subtract an additional length of `\lastskip` and `\baselineskip` at the end (one `\baselineskip` because the `verse` environment acts as an paragraph and you could actually begin another one on the next line) which adds up to `2\baselineskip`.

This solution is still “ugly” as it is needed to type `\compress` as well as `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}` every time, so I defined a new environment, called `tvserse`.

A third (localized) solution is the definition of a new column type `V` that takes two (mandatory) arguments:

1. the actual optional argument for the `verse` environment (use `{}` for the non-usage of this argment), and
2. the width of the underlying `p` column.

The whole cell is now typeset as a verse.

If the `array` package is used an additional `\leavevmode` is needed in the first two cases.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{tverse}[1][]{\compress\ifx\\#1\\\begin{verse}\else\begin{verse}[#1]\fi}{\end{verse}\vspace{-\lastskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\newcolumntype{V}[2]{%
    >{%
        \compress%
        \ifx\\#1\\%
            \begin{verse}%
        \else%
            \verse[#1]%
        \fi%
    }%
    p{#2}%
    <{%
        \end{verse}%
        \vspace{-\lastskip}%
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{30mm} | p{30mm} | p{30mm}}
  \hline 1. & \compress \begin{verse} AAAA \\
                                      BBBB \\
                                      CCCC \end{verse} \vspace{-\lastskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\leavevmode & QUESTION \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{30mm} | p{30mm} | p{30mm}}
  \hline 1. & \begin{tverse} AAAA \\
                             BBBB \\
                             CCCC \end{tverse} & QUESTION \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{30mm} | V{}{30mm} | p{30mm}}
  \hline 1. &  AAAA \\
               BBBB \\
               CCCC & QUESTION \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works! However, the output doesn't match what I see from compiling the code: I see some space at the end of the verse environment. Maybe you should change the output image so that it is correct?

Comment: @user856624 Yes, that was a confusion on my side. I've added a third solution to my answer and updated code and output image as well.