# Remove unwanted vertical space before and after environment in footnote

Tags: spacing, environments, footnotes, memoir

I am trying to make my own environment for (left-)indented blocks inside hanging footnotes, in which the normal `quote` environment doesn't work, it's left indent being the same as that of the indent of the footnote, so that one doesn't see it. I am now trying to do to this with the adjustwidth environment, which does the indentation as I want it, but it inserts horizontal spaces before and after the environment if there's nothing before or after it in the footnote, a behaviour which the `quote` environment also seems to have.

I tried to adapt the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83275/how-to-eliminate-vertical-space-before-and-after-verse-environment), but the `\compress` didn't seem to do anything, and the negative `\vspace` after the environment would pull the next line, if there was one, into last line of the environment.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}
\newenvironment{fnquote}[1][]{\compress\ifx\\#1\\\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5\leftmargin}{}\else\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5\leftmargin}{}[#1]\fi}{\end{adjustwidth}\vspace{-\lastskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{Enough text to be two lines in the footnote. Enough text to be two lines in the footnote. Enough text to be two lines in the footnote.
\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5\leftmargin}{}
And here we have a quote inside the footnote. With some text before or after it it looks fine, but ...
\end{adjustwidth}
Some text after the quote.
}
\footnote{
\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5\leftmargin}{}
If I have a footnote starting or ending with a quotation I get an empty line, before or after, which I don't want.
\end{adjustwidth}
}
\footnote{
\begin{fnquote}
If I have a footnote starting or ending with a quotation I get an empty line, before or after, which I don't want.
\end{fnquote}
And some more text here.
}
\footnote{Just another footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Is there maybe another switch I could use to trick the environment into thinking there was some text before and after it in the footnote?

Comment: My question is: wouldn't it be better to typeset the quotation in a different font rather than with narrower text width in the footnote? Without any text before it, the quote would look strange even if the empty line problem gets fixed.

Comment: Before and after the footnote text, LaTeX inserts a strut, that's used for making the distance between consecutive footnotes right. The `fnquote` environment (or `adjustwidth`) starts and ends with `\par`, so the two struts get eventually in lines by themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really what you want: the result is just wrong, nobody will understand why the text in the second and third footnote is shifted right.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}

\newenvironment{fnquote}
 {\par
  \setbox0=\lastbox \setbox2=\hbox{\unhcopy0}%
  \ifdim\wd2>\leftmargin \nointerlineskip\else\prevdepth=\dp\strutbox\fi\box0
  \vspace{-2.83337pt plus -1.41669pt minus -0.94446pt}%
  \ifdim\wd2>\leftmargin \else\vspace{-\baselineskip}\fi
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1.5\leftmargin}{}}
 {\end{adjustwidth}\vspace{-2.83337pt plus -1.41669pt minus -0.94446pt}}
\newenvironment{fnquote*}
 {\fnquote}{\endfnquote\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{%
  Enough text to be two lines in the footnote. Enough text to be two 
  lines in the footnote. Enough text to be two lines in the footnote.
  \begin{fnquote}
    And here we have a quote inside the footnote. With some text before or after
    it it looks fine, but ...
  \end{fnquote}
  Some text after the quote.}
\footnote{%
  \begin{fnquote*}
  If I have a footnote starting or ending with a quotation I get an empty line,
  before or after, which I don't want.
  \end{fnquote*}
}
\footnote{%
  \begin{fnquote}
  If I have a footnote starting or ending with a quotation I get an empty line,
  before or after, which I don't want.
  \end{fnquote}
  And some more text here.
}
\footnote{Just another footnote.}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that any footnote has two implicit struts at the beginning and end; when `fnquote` appears at the beginning, it does a `\par` and so the strut forms a paragraph by itself. Similarly, if no text follows `fnquote`, the final strut makes a paragraph by itself.

I measure the last typeset line and if it is longer than `\leftmargin`, it means it has text; otherwise I back up what's necessary.

For quotes ending the footnote, it's necessary to use a different environment `fnquote*` that backs up by a baselineskip.

[image]

Comment: Interesting to see the use of `\lastbox`.  I agree with your comment about reader confusion regarding the indentation.  Nevertheless, is there a handy way to clean up the interline spacing between footnote 2 and 3?  It looks a bit tight.  And perhaps the same can be said about the end of the quote in footnote 3 and its following text.

Comment: @A.Ellett It's not meant to be a full solution (there are some strange effects indeed. Fixed now.

Comment: I only asked because I'd been playing with this for a bit.  Never would have come up with your solution (not entirely sure I'd ever have thought about shifting around the boxes at the beginning).  I'd been thinking of doing a `\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}` sort of thing, but didn't see how to apply it to what you'd done.

Comment: @A.Ellett I didn't try with `\footnote{\begin{fnquote}...\end{fnquote}` as the first on a page. But it seems to work well. `;-)`