# reduce space before and after verse environment

Tags: spacing

I want to reduce globally in a document the vertical space before and after a verse environment.  The MWE shows the problem, with output:
[image: Imgur]

I would like not to use other packages, because I want to learn some low-level commands.  I know that `verse` is based on a `list` environment. A related answer ([How to eliminate vertical space before and after verse environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83275/how-to-eliminate-vertical-space-before-and-after-verse-environment)) seems overly complex, and uses the `verse` package (not the built-in version).  Surely there is a way to

`\setlength{\versesep}{0pt}`

or something like it?

Or (since I am using `xpatch` package anyway), could I do something like

`\xpatchcmd\verse{\...`

But I don't know how to find the original code for the `verse` environment, and so I don't know which line to modify.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.  Separated nicely.

\begin{verse}
This is some\\
lovely verse,\\
that has too much space\\
on top and below.
\end{verse}

I would really like not as much space above and below.  Just one parskip would be sufficient.

But other paragraphs should be spaced with parskip.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}` (that doesn't make much sense anyway).

Comment: This will affect the normal paragraphs, which I don't want to do.  I just edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the added `\parskip` by reducing `\topsep`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\xpatchcmd{\verse}{\itemsep}{\advance\topsep-\parskip\itemsep}{}{}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph.

\begin{verse}
This is some\\
lovely verse,\\
that has too much space\\
on top and below.
\end{verse}

I would really like not as much space above and below.  Just one parskip would be sufficient

I would really like not as much space above and below.  Just one parskip would be sufficient

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compiled your solution inside my real document (two columned, landscape) and the vertical space still looked too big, until I added 'ragged bottom', which fixed things.  Can you add to your answer please how to limit the stretchiness inside the \verse command so that I do not need the \raggedbottom?

Comment: @Tim Two column and raggedbottom don't go along; in this case you are responsible of setting the spacing parameters so that columns are filled up correctly. Possibly adding a bit of stretching or shrinking to such a gigantic `\parskip` can help.

Answer (score 2):

Without other packages, maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\let\oldverse\verse
\renewenvironment{verse}{%
    \vspace{-\parskip}
    \oldverse
}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.  Separated nicely.

\begin{verse}
This is some\\
lovely verse,\\
that has too much space\\
on top and below.
\end{verse}

I would really like not as much space above and below.  Just one parskip would be sufficient.

But other paragraphs should be spaced with parskip.

\end{document}
```

[image]