# Can I begin a list inline but have subsequent items below that

Tags: itemize

I have the following code:

```
Duties & \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                \item Inventory management; ordering and full monthly count
```

This outputs "Duties" and then a new line with the item, and several items follow. This falls within a larger table formed using tabularx. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the new line and have "Inventory management..." fall to the right of "Duties" but then every subsequent item be below that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a compilable code of what you've tried?

Comment: Does this question describe the same problem you're having? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6445/172164

Comment: @TivV yes, actually, that is exactly what I was trying to do and it worked perfectly. Thank you, I don't know how I didn't find that in my searches prior to posting.

Comment: @user207664 Glad it helped! Some days the search-fu just isn't strong enough :)